# Pop sounds at intersection of overlapping envelopes

Tags: noise, audio-processing, signal-synthesis

I am currently dabbeling with programming a real-time audio software and I already got a simple pipeline where notes can be played and released and each note has its own envelope so that the amplitude of each note signal begins and ends at 0 smoothly.

However, I am currently running into the problem that if 2 notes overlap not exactly, there are pop sounds appearing at the intersection points. So for example, if a note sounds from 0 to 1 s and another note from 0.5 to 1.5 s, there are pop sounds at 0.5 and 1 s.

I am not sure why there would be discontinuities there. If there is no overlap or the notes overlap exactly, there are no pop sounds.

Anyone have an idea, what could be the issue?

The samples are mixed via the arithmetic mean and the envelopes I have tried so far were with linear/quadratic fade-in/out. The underlying waves are single sinusoids.

**UPDATE**

I think, I found the issue. It is the arithmetic mean, I think @KnutInge alluded to that issue, the normalization factor I use is the inverse of the currently active notes, so if that changes from a frame to the next, the amplitude changes drastically.

I am not sure, how to handle this. Should I compute the interpolation factor via the envelope values? Basically something like
$$\alpha = \frac{envelope_0}{envelope_0+envelope_1}$$
and then
$$sample = \alpha\cdot sample_0 + (1-\alpha)\cdot sample_1$$?
This generalizes to arbitrary amounts of active notes, right?

Comment: Can you share a plot of 1)the first note, 2)the second note, 3)the mix, all zoomed closely in at eg 0.5 seconds? By «arithmetic mean» do you mean that the mixer output is a static (a+b)/2, or  do you change the normalization when the number of notes changes?

Comment: You might be clipping

Comment: I mean the general arithmetic mean, yes,where it is divided by the number of notes. I will upload plots as soon as possible, hopefully today.

Comment: Are you are using floating point, fractional or integer math ?

Comment: @KnutInge, please checkout the update, I think I have found the issue.

Comment: @Hilmar, please checkout the update, I think I have found the issue.

Comment: Why are you normalizing at all? In real life one tone does not get softer when another tone plays in. Also the total wave amplitude of the summation depends on the relative phase of the two notes, etc. and does not multiply according to number of notes especially not as the number of notes increases. I would simply calculate the envelope of each note independently and add their per-sample output without any normalization. If you need to make sure that the total does not exceed the max amplitude available, don't play each note at full amplitude, also add a sample-by-sample limiter to handle cli

Answer (score 1):

The most straight forward approach would be to mix as :
`(tone1 + tone2 +…) / max_number_of_tones`

Comment: This does work better than my proposed solution since I still get popping when notes are in release phase with that version (still no idea why, especially why does the attack phase work then?). I like straightforward, but is this like, "pretty close to optimal" though?